# Can I check in a 35-kg suitcase?

Tags: delta-air-lines, korean-air

I booked a flight with Delta (operated by Korean Air). I plan to check in one 35-kg suitcase instead of two 23-kg suitcases. Some people state that it should be avoided as much as possible, but the last time I booked a flight with American Airlines from Chicago, America to Hanoi, Vietnam, I checked in a 41-kg suitcase and they still accepted it. Is it acceptable with Delta?

Comment: Their website should say, have you looked there? Spoiler alert: a fee is likely involved

Comment: It's pretty common to see a 32kg/70lb limit (as in anything heavier is not accepted, even if you pay extra) as an employee safety measure, though some airlines will go to 100lbs.

Comment: American Airlines has a max weight per item of 100 lb / 45 kg, but in my experience that is an exception (and they actually have a 32 kg limit on many routes, including to/from Europe or Australia). Most airlines have a maximum allowed weight of 32 kg per item, as is the case for Korean Air as stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 12):

[Korean Air's luggage policy](https://www.koreanair.com/mobile/global/en/traveling/baggage-services/free-baggage-and-baggage-fee.html) (you're flying with KAL so it's their policy that applies) says:

> - The maximum size (width + heights + depth) is 158cm/62in and the maximum weight per bag is 23kg/ 50lb or 32kg/70lb depending on your ticket class and itineraries. Bags between 23 and 32kg (51–70lb) may incur additional charges depending on your allowance.
> - For the safety of the baggage handlers, some countries might restrict any items that exceeds the maximum weight and/or size (width + height + depth) for a single piece, 32kg/70lb, 158cm/62in regardless of seat class and/or extra baggage payment.

If you're flying economy, you won't be able to check in bags heavier than 23 kg. Or even 32 kg if you're flying business. Pack two bags.

Comment: Per [the baggage calculator](https://www.koreanair.com/mobile/global/en/traveling/baggage-services/ebaggage-calculator.html#calc), you can check in bags between 23-32kg, but you'll have to pay a fee. That doesn't help the OP since their bag exceeds 32kg, but it is possible, just not free, to check in bags heavier than 23kg in economy.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on your ticket class; in business class or first they are more accommodating and generous than in economy.

However, be aware that being over the weight limits may cost you *significant* extra money, or you may simply not be allowed to fly. Don't risk this.

If it is important to you to have only one suitcase to handle at your destination, try to pack something simple like a duffel-bag separately, and put it *inside* the bigger luggage - the extra fabric and weight of the duffel bag itself will be negligible.

Take it out at the check-in counter, check the two separately (=free), and at arrival, just open the larger suitcase and put the whole duffel bag back into it.